# Twitter Bootstrap and Less in Visual Studio 2012 MCV4 issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Well I think I have gone mad.  I have a handful of MVC4 VS 2010 projects that all use Twitter Bootstrap/Less, that I am now using in VS 2012 with no problems.  However, whenever I try to create a new MVC4 internet project, and mimic the setup I used on other 2010 projects for Bootstrap, it will not work! In the Chrome console, it shows this:

[image]

Both files are there, and I have spent half my Saturday trying to figure out what the @#($@#*$ is going on.  Here is my file setup in VS 2012:

[image]

And here is my header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/Content/themes/Admin/less/bootstrap.less" type="text/css" />
<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/themes/Admin/less-1.3.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/Admin/js/bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/js/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Can anyone see any obvious mistakes? I've tried a whole bunch of different combinations, but I am trying to keep this as simple as I can for now.  Thanks for your time!

Comment: You can get rid of the Url.Content references in MVC4 and just use ~/ in all your paths (http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-the-new-tilde-slash-feature-in-razor-2), which will clean things up a little - you don't have that in your less stylesheet reference, which may be part of the problem. Also, could you change your post image to expand the less folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you missing a MIME type for .less?

Try adding the following to the `system.webServer` section of your web.config.

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />
</staticContent>
```

Or [add a MIME type in IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Well in the interest of time, I just decided to go ahead and pre-compile my .less files via WinLess.  Having the LESS javascript file working in dev just helps to speed things up, but oh